# @available fails to prevent calls to functions in swift

Tags: swift

I am using `@available` to prevent some functions to be called at certain OS versions. Lets say I have two functions and both should be restricted to macOS version 12 and below. Not available at macOS 13. Hence I want to write

```swift
@available(macOS, obsoleted: 12)
extension MyStruct {
    func myFunc1() -> String { ... }
    func myFunc2() {
        let resultOfCallOfMyFunc1 = myFunc1()
    }
}
```

I thought that this way both functions are only available at the same platfroms. But I am getting error, when I try to use `myFunc1` in `myFunc2` why is that?

The error is: `"myFunc1()" is unavailable in macOS`

I also tried to mark each function separately instead of marking the whole extension, but no luck there either.

Any reason why this fails? How to use @available the way, that I will be able to use one function inside another one?

Comment: macOS 12 is my minimum version. Hence obsoleted contains the last version in which you can use the function this should be fine. **this was answer to deleted question of what is my minimum target os**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Language Reference](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Attributes.html#ID583), `obsoleted` indicates the *first* version in which the member is unavailable.

> The `obsoleted` argument indicates the first version of the specified platform or language in which the declaration was obsoleted.

So you should write `obsoleted: 13` instead. `obsolete: 12` would mean that the extension is obsolete since macOS 12. Assuming that your minimum deployment target is equal to or higher than macOS 12, this would mean that the extension is obsolete on all the possible devices your app will be installed on, hence "`myFunc1` is unavailable".

Note that the `obsolete` argument prevents code that targets higher OS versions from *compiling*. It is still possible to compile code targeting a lower version, and run `myFunc1` on macOS 13+. If you don't want `myFunc1` to *execute* at all on macOS 13+ at all. You should use an `#unavailable` check:

```
if #unavailable(macOS 13, *) {
    let resultOfCallOfMyFunc1 = myFunc1()
}
```

Comment: Oh ok, I was thinking according to the https://www.avanderlee.com/swift/available-deprecated-renamed/#unavailability-condition-using-unavailable article where it is stated otherwise... will give this a try

Comment: So if I understand this correctly if my minimum macOS version would be 11, and I want my functions to be available on macOS 11, 12 and not 13. I would mark it with obsoleted: 13 Thanks

Comment: Then @Sweeper why when I mark my functions like @available(macOS, obsoleted: 11.5) I can still run them on macOS 12 ?

Comment: @JasonKrowl I cannot reproduce that. It gives the same error for me.

Comment: Hmm... thanks anyways. I have to look somewhere else for the issue afterwards..

Comment: Because @Sweeper when I try to `@available(iOS, obsoleted: 14.6)
extension myStructView {` and I run this code on iOS simulator with 15.5 it still runs the functions inside the extension. The original error is gone, So I assume you solved the issue here. But still I would need to stop execution of these functions

Comment: @JasonKrowl I think I understand what you want to do. You want to only run `myFunc1` *at runtime* when the device is running a certain OS version or below? That's the use case for `if #unavailable(macOS 13, *) { myFunc1() }`. `@available` is a *compile-time* thing.